# Adding histogram bins together and plotting a figure

Tags: python, plot, data-binding, histogram, data-fitting

I have a histogram with 8192 bins, each bin imported from a line from a text file. To cut things short, it makes an awful fit and it was suggested to mee I could reduce the statistical errors by adding counts from adjacent bins. e.g. add bins 0-7 to make a new first bin, 8 times as wide, but 8 times(roughly) as high.

Ideally, would like to just be able to output a histogram of a binwidth controlled by a single constant in the code. However my attempts to do this, instead of producing something like the first image below (which was born of the version of my code which can only do a binwidth of 1, produce something like the second image below, missing fit lines and with a second empty graph in the same image file (born of my attempts to generalise the code for any bin width).
The following a histogram plotted directly from the original data i.e. binwidth = 1
Original code output, only works for binwidth 1 though.

[image: Original data]

Example for trying bin width 8 with come code modifications

[image: Bin Width 8]

I also need it to return a fit report, and the area under the gaussian as this is plotted later on in the code, in an exponential decay curve.

Here is the section of code I think is relevant:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import exp, loadtxt, pi, sqrt, random, linspace
from lmfit import Model
import glob, os

    ## Load text file
    x = np.linspace(0, 8191, 8192)
    finalprefix = str(n).zfill(3)
    fullprefix = folderToAnalyze + prefix + finalprefix
    y = loadtxt(fullprefix + ".Spe", skiprows= 12, max_rows = 8192) 

    ## Make figure and label
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
    fig.suptitle('Photon coincidence detections from $β^+$ + $β^-$ annhilation', fontsize=18)
    plt.xlabel('Bins', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('Counts', fontsize=14)

    ## Plot data
    ax.bar(x, y)
    ax.set_xlim(600,960)
    
    ##  Adding Bins Together
    y = y.astype(int)
    x = x.astype(int)

    ## create the data
    data = np.repeat(x, y)

    ## determine the range of x
    x_range = range(min(data), max(data)+1)

    ## determine the length of x
    x_len = len(x_range)

    ## plot
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(10, 10))

    ax1.hist(data, bins=x_len)  # outliers are not plotted
    plt.show()
    
    ## given x_len determine how many bins for a given bin width
    width = 8
    bins = int(np.round(x_len / width))

    ## determine new x and y for the histogram
    y, x = np.histogram(data, bins=bins)

    ## Fit data to Gaussian
    gmodel = Model(gaussian)
    result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x[:-1], amp=8, cen=approxcen, wid=1)

    ## result
    print(result.fit_report())
    fig.savefig("abw_" + finalprefix + ".png")
        
    ## Append to list if error in amplitude and amplitude itself is within reasonable bounds
    if result.params['amp'].stderr < stderrThreshold and result.params['amp'] > minimumAmplitude:
        amps.append(result.params['amp'].value) 
        ampserr.append(result.params['amp'].stderr) 
        ts.append(MaestroT*n)

## Plot decay curve
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(ts, amps, yerr= 2*np.array(ampserr), fmt="ko-", capsize = 5, capthick= 2, elinewidth=3, markersize=5)
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Peak amplitude', fontsize=14)
plt.title("Decay curve of P-31 by $β^+$ emission", fontsize=14)
```

Some synthetic data: {1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,3,0,0,3,3,3,5,4,0,4,3,1,4,0,5,6,4,0,2,0,0,0,9,6,1,1,1,0,0,3,2,2,3,0,0,0,2,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,10,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
I think this should create 2 very different shaped histograms when the bin width is 1 and when it is 8. Though I have just made them up, the fit may not be good, and it is worth mentioning one of the problems I was having is related to being able to add together the information read in from the text file

In case it's useful:

-Here is the [full](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k63xky6ibvto3r0/Histogram.ipynb?dl=0) original code

-Here is the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dyunrpwu8nr96ef/DECAY_COINC003.Spe?dl=0) for that histogram

Comment: sorry, your example is too long and complex for me to follow.  But why do you say that the first fit you show (both plot and embedded output text) is bad?

Comment: maybe a likelyhood fit would be better

Comment: Admittedly that's one of the better fits, there are about 500 of these. Just thought it'd be easier to see. A chi^2 value of 97 doesn't usually indicate a good fit. And you can the bin counts often vary quite a lot from the fit line - this is mostly because in the 18s for each bin you get quite few counts. 
It was suggested to me one remedy to this, is to add the counts for multiple bins together, say add 2 bins together and represent 1 36s window with twice as many counts. This means the statistical fluctuations would appear lesser and a fit would be easier to apply.

Comment: Thing is, when I try to do that, following an example from another question i asked a while back, I get that example with 2 figures - 1 with no fitting and 1 with no data.

Comment: What would make it a bit easier to follow? Also nice to meet another accelerator folk - I am an experimental officer at a pelletron in the UK

Comment: How would I implement a likelihood fit? I'm pretty new to python. (And programming in general)

Comment: @MNewville Added a little bit on the end of the post to try to explain it

Comment: Also editted the code example to try and make it more concise and readable.

Comment: @Epideme It seems like the question is: "why is the fit (or are the fits) not as good as I would like it (them) to be?".  That suggests that everything is working from the programming and algorithm perspective, and you're "just" unhappy with the result.  Maybe the model is incorrect or incomplete (like there should be another component or something).  If that is not the question, please follow the SO guide for providing a minimal and complete example that shows the problem you are having.

Comment: As far as I see, you just have counts. So you would decompose the histogram into measured x values. From this e.g. the `scipy.stat` could do a parameter fit. [Here](https://gist.github.com/plasmaman/5508278) is a handmade example for a likelyhood fit.

Comment: @MNewville It's a little of both, ultimately, I would like a better fit, which isn't anything to do with the programming side of thing. The way it was suggested to me that I might attain about doing that, was to add histogram bins together to increase counts and decrease statistical uncertainties. Which is what i'm trying (albeit, unsuccessfully) to implement here, due to programming problems

Comment: @MNewville Might be easier to follow now, tried to provide a more concise version of the problem

Comment: When you combine bins you always loose information.

Comment: Yep, it seems like a poor choice to proceed in my opinion for that reason. But it's what my supervisor is insisting on, so keeping the powder dry

Comment: No...seriously...make a log likelyhood fit. That should be standard in high energy physics.

Comment: Alright, i'll go for that as soon as I get this one squared away. Need to learn how to implement it first as well, which might take a while - bit new to all this.